# Keep other column values constant after groupby and manipulating sub-dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I want to group `dfx` by `Branch` and `Buyer`, get the row where `Quantity` is middle value in each sub-dataframe, and return the final dataframe. How can I keep the corresponding value in the `Date` column as well?

`dfx`:

```
  Branch Buyer  Quantity                Date
0      A  Carl         1 2013-01-01 13:00:00
1      A  Mark         3 2013-01-01 13:05:00
2      A  Carl         5 2013-10-01 20:00:00
3      A  Carl         1 2013-10-02 10:00:00
4      A   Joe         8 2013-10-01 20:00:00
5      A   Joe         1 2013-10-02 10:00:00
6      A   Joe         9 2013-12-02 12:00:00
7      B  Carl         3 2013-12-02 14:00:00
```

Reproducible sample:

```
 dfx = pd.DataFrame({'Branch': 'A A A A A A A B'.split(),
   'Buyer': 'Carl Mark Carl Carl Joe Joe Joe Carl'.split(),
   'Quantity': [1, 3, 5, 1, 8, 1, 9, 3],
   'Date': [
   datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 13, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 13, 5),
   datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 1, 20, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 2, 10, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 1, 20, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 2, 10, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 2, 12, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 2, 14, 0)]
   })
```

Using:

```
grouped1 = dfx.groupby(['Branch', 'Buyer'])
grouped1['Quantity'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
```

returned:

```
Branch  Buyer
A       Carl     1
        Joe      8
        Mark     3
B       Carl     3
Name: Quantity, dtype: int64
```

but not keeping `Date`.

---

Expected output for middle value in `Quantity`:

```
  Branch Buyer  Quantity                Date
0      A  Carl         1 2013-01-01 13:00:00  
1      A  Mark         3 2013-01-01 13:05:00

4      A   Joe         8 2013-10-01 20:00:00

7      B  Carl         3 2013-12-02 14:00:00
```

For `(A,Carl)`, there are only two unique values `1` and `5`, but `1` appeared first so keeping this row. `(A,Joe)` has `8, 1, 9`, so keeping the row with middle value which is `8`. `(A,Mark)` and `(B,Carl)` has only one row in total so keeping the original data.

Comment: which date do you want? there is more than one date for each branch-buyer combination, hence the reason for doing groupby, right?

Comment: @AlexS1 I'd like to find the middle value of `Quantity` in each sub-dataframe. If there are even number of values, take either one in the middle of the list.

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael please see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with get indices of difference with median and absolute values with [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) and then select rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.sub(x.median()).abs().idxmin()
df = dfx.loc[dfx.groupby(['Branch', 'Buyer'], sort=False)['Quantity'].apply(f)]
print (df)
  Branch Buyer  Quantity                Date
0      A  Carl         1 2013-01-01 13:00:00
1      A  Mark         3 2013-01-01 13:05:00
4      A   Joe         8 2013-10-01 20:00:00
7      B  Carl         3 2013-12-02 14:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. If we use median, what happens when there are even number of values in the sub-dataframe? If `median` calculates the average, it is not the actual data in `Quantity` right?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - It is no problem, because there is difference with median, so get minimal row, it means close value of median.

Answer (score 3):

[Groupby Extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvBeO.png)

To get the middle element of Quantity you can take the first and the last index and divide by 2 to get the middle index. Corresponding to the value of Quantity you will get the Date column just by specifying the column name i.e. Date after groupby as shown above.